# How to Get the ID for the Simulator that is generated in XCTestDevices

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcuitest, xctestcase

Is there a way to get the ID of the Simulator that is generated in the Library/Developer/XCTestDevices folder?

When I do:

```
UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor
```

This gives me an ID but not the one I need:

▿ Optional

- some : 6DB17918-2E92-4375-826F-55EE320AE3A8

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run in Terminal

```
xcrun simctl list
```